# Create Mail alert using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, cordova

I want to know how can I create mail alert using jQuery mobile (javascript, html5). This alert consists of alerting the user when a new announcement is added (the announcement will be added in the base of joomla, I have a site joomla synchronised with an application phonegap, in the application the customer will do a search of property, if is not exist, he can save her research, and when a new announcement posted he can receive an alert mail about this add)

Please help me

Comment: So you want to send an email? Based on if an announcement is made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a monitoring system in place on your sever to find when an announcement is posted (I assume you have PHP or similar already handling this part).

Once you have that in place, you need to use **Server-Side Code** to send an email. It would be a rather large spam issue if anyone could send emails from Javascript.

PHP has the following function available to you:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

You must use `From: me@example.com` in your header, and separate header attributes by `\r\n`.

-

**The monitoring system:**

You say you have the [JEA Joomla extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/real-estate/6755), which is used to post announcements. I assume that it has a PHP file to handle the addition of new announcements.

Simply add your function at the bottom of that PHP page, and what should happen is that when the PHP file is called to add a new announcement, your function will also be called, and the users will be automatically notified.

Comment: please have you an example of monitoring system??

Comment: Can you please explain (preferably in your question) how a new announcement is posted? This will allow me to edit my answer with the relevant information.

Comment: the annoncement will be added in the base of joomla, I have a site joomla synchronised with an application phonegap, in the application the customer will do a search of property, if is not exist, he can save her research, and when a new anoncement posted he can receive an alert mail about this add

Comment: Ok, I'm really busy at the moment, but I will post in about ~8 hours

Comment: So you are basically editing the web page manually to add an announcement?

Comment: I have in joomla a composant (JEA) in which I will add a new annoncement, I have searching the function in which I will save a new annoncement